# Compile QJson on Windows with MinGW

Tags: windows, qt, qjson

I'm trying to compile [QJson](https://github.com/flavio/qjson) library for my Qt project and run it on Windows.
I've downloaded zip from GitHub and follow this instructions on [project website](http://qjson.sourceforge.net/build/):

1. created build folder
2. cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..
3. mingw32-make
   and got next error:
   [image: Command output]

If I comment #include  then it says locale_t type is unknown.
So how to compile it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found workaround. I was downloaded from official website QJson 0.8.1(newest for today), but it doesn't work. On forum I found someone's comment that now QJson doesn't support windows. On official website I haven't found this information so I don't know is it true.

But I've downloaded version 0.7.1 and it has compiled without any errors. Here is the link:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/qjson/files/qjson/0.7.1/

Comment: You saved me a lot of time!

Comment: Just copmiled lastest version (0.8.1) fine on Windows.

Comment: That's great. Please share your experience as an answer here. I guess it would be useful for community.